# What's the next term in this sequence?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

I created this simple number sequence puzzle, I don't know if anyone used the same idea before. Find the term at the question mark in the sequence.

$$
25, 42, 56, 97, 176, 232, 251, 269, 394, 518, 572, 656, 853, 989, 1663, 1787, ?
$$

Comment: Well, I can't find the sequence on OEIS, so apparently it's not a well-known thing.

Comment: If you can't find it in OEIS, the rule is probably not mathematical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is

> 2202

Because

> 2202 = 1787 + 1x7x8x7 + 1+7+8+7